# Floating action bar with search

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create a map layout with a search in actionbar.

Here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

So far I tried it with a cardview but it's not a proper way. I need this thing to work as a real actionbar. Maybe using a custom toolbar may help but I need some suggestions.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="11dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/search_location_hint"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try using relative layout

Answer (score 0):

**For Floating Toolbar:** Use Toolbar widget & Provide some margin from Left, Top, Right.

**For Rounded corner:** Use shape background in Toolbar.